# Logging in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I'm working on a web application that handles a bit of traffic. I tried using FileHandler, set up when handling each request, for logging but that resulted in wsgi crashing from too many open files, current limit is 1024 which seems reasonable.

How do people handle logging when dealing with a bit of traffic? Is there a way for the wsgi process to use one filehandle for all requests?

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with a sufficient logger that should handle many requests at once.

For example:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("web2py.app.myweb2pyapplication")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Then, in your code:

```
logger.error("Something went wrong! Error:"+str(e)
```

or

```
logger.debug("Still trying to figure this out. Checkpoint 3")
```

Python logging: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

If this doesn't suit your needs, more advanced logging is available here: 
http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1416/logging

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was using this, the problem is how to add a handler than doesn't require an open file, thereby using one of the usually 1024 file handles.

Comment: create a `model/logger.py` with basic configuration you need and then use it anywhere in your `web2py` application.